# How to compare dates in a ReactiveMongo BSON query?

Tags: mongodb, date, bson, reactivemongo

I'm using ReactiveMongo without the Play fremework.

I'm trying to write the equivalent of the following simple MongoDB query :

```
db.oplog.rs.find({"o.TimeCreated":{"$gt": ISODate("2014-09-30T10:00:00.000Z")}})
```

I've tried things like :

```
val query = BSONDocument(
        "o.TimeCreated" -> BSONDocument("$gt" -> BSONDateTime(ts))) // ts is the timestamp corresponding to the date "2014-09-30T10:00:00.000Z"
```

hoping that the "$gt" operator would work for comparing two BSONDateTime objects, assuming the value of "o.TimeCreated" would internally be represented as a BSONDateTime object.

But I can't seem to figure out how to make the query work (no data is returned).

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: I should probably add that in MongoDB, the value of "o.TimeCreated" is stored as an ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a few options for you to try:

- You might want to try BSONTimestamp instead of BSONDateTime in your query
- Do the documents in oplog.rs collection have a top level object named "o.TimeCreated"?
- Is there an object in the collection that can satisfy the query with the timestamp you've using?